# How to make multipart/form-data multiples propreties required in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

Swagger execution works but it displays "unvalid" for multiple required propreties.
this is the error message:

```
{"messages":["attribute paths.'/smile_video'(post).requestBody.content.'multipart/form-data'.schema.required is not of type `array`"],"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","domain":"validation","keyword":"oneOf","message":"instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 2)","schema":{"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/definitions/Operation/properties/requestBody"},"instance":{"pointer":"/paths/~1smile_video/post/requestBody"}}]}
```

This is the request body definition:

```
  "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "video",
                  "encodings"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "video": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary",
                    "description": "Upload video file"
                  },
                  "encodings": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "binary",
                    "description": "Upload video file "
                  
                  }
                }
              } 
            }
          }
        }
```

[This is the swagger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx8Gr.png)

Comment: Your example is correct. If you paste the full API definition into https://editor.swagger.io, does it report any errors or warnings?

Comment: No the execution works fine. I disabled the validation to not display the validation error. I added an answer for this.

Comment: Also consider raising a bug with the Validator badge here: https://github.com/swagger-api/validator-badge/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable validation by adding validatorUrl : false

```
   const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "***",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        validatorUrl : false,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ]
      });
```